# Fail to compile python with Cython on Windows 7

Tags: python, c, windows, visual-studio, cython

I am trying to compile my python project, and I compile the main file with PyInstaller, and the rest with Cython.

On linux it all goes well, but when I tried on Windows 7, it didn't work. I had to install the .NET framework 4.6, and then the visual studio build tools 2019. It all installed well, even though it took ages, and I tried running the setup.py file again, but this time I got this error:

```
running build_ext
building 'objects.blocks' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\Kolterdyx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\include -IC:\Users\Kolterdyx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcbuild\objects/blocks.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\build\objects/blocks.obj
blocks.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Users\Kolterdyx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\Kolterdyx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\lib\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x64" /EXPORT:PyInit_blocks build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\build\objects/blocks.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\objects\blocks.cp38-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\build\objects\blocks.cp38-win_amd64.lib
   Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\build\objects\blocks.cp38-win_amd64.lib y objeto build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\build\objects\blocks.cp38-win_amd64.exp
Generating code
Code generation finished
building 'objects.enemy' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\Kolterdyx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\include -IC:\Users\Kolterdyx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcbuild\objects/enemy.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\build\objects/enemy.obj
enemy.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Users\Kolterdyx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\Kolterdyx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\lib\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x64" /EXPORT:PyInit_enemy build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\build\objects/enemy.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\objects\enemy.cp38-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\build\objects\enemy.cp38-win_amd64.lib
   Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\build\objects\enemy.cp38-win_amd64.lib y objeto build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\build\objects\enemy.cp38-win_amd64.exp
Generating code
Code generation finished
building 'objects.item' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\Kolterdyx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\include -IC:\Users\Kolterdyx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcbuild\objects/item.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\build\objects/item.obj
item.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Users\Kolterdyx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\Kolterdyx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\lib\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x64" /EXPORT:PyInit_item build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\build\objects/item.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\objects\item.cp38-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\build\objects\item.cp38-win_amd64.lib
   Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\build\objects\item.cp38-win_amd64.lib y objeto build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\build\objects\item.cp38-win_amd64.exp
Generating code
Code generation finished
building 'objects.player' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\Kolterdyx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\include -IC:\Users\Kolterdyx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcbuild\objects/player.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\build\objects/player.obj
player.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Users\Kolterdyx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\Kolterdyx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\lib\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x64" /EXPORT:PyInit_player build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\build\objects/player.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\objects\player.cp38-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\build\objects\player.cp38-win_amd64.lib
   Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\build\objects\player.cp38-win_amd64.lib y objeto build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\build\objects\player.cp38-win_amd64.exp
Generating code
Code generation finished
building 'objects.PhysicObjects.__init__' extension
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\build\objects\PhysicObjects
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\Kolterdyx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\include -IC:\Users\Kolterdyx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcbuild\objects/PhysicObjects/__init__.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\build\objects/PhysicObjects/__init__.obj
__init__.c
creating Z:\Programming\Python\GameDev\VoidShips\build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\objects\PhysicObjects
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Users\Kolterdyx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\Kolterdyx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\lib\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x64" /EXPORT:PyInit___init__ build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\build\objects/PhysicObjects/__init__.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\objects\PhysicObjects\__init__.cp38-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\build\objects/PhysicObjects\__init__.cp38-win_amd64.lib
LINK : error LNK2001: external symbol PyInit___init__ not resolved
build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\build\objects/PhysicObjects\__init__.cp38-win_amd64.lib : fatal error LNK1120: 1 external not resolved
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.26.28801\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Better translate it right away if you want help from a pure English community (officially at least and if you want all of it to be able to help).

Comment: But basically: do you really need to compile `__init__.py`?

Comment: @ead not really, my setup.py file just does a os.walk to get all the files in the package. Could that be causing the problem?